# Recieve errors when attempting to insert user_id along with an array from a form meant to submit multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a simple form that lets a user type in multiple 'isbn' entries in a form. Upon submission each field should input a new record into the database including the isbn entered and the logged in user's ID. I've tried many searches, but none of the solutions mention are working for me.

Controller:

First I tested this code below to make sure it was capturing the id and the entered isbn, but of course i fed it a user_id to insert, which is not what I want-

```
public function wanted(Request $request)
    {
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;
        $booklist = Input::get('isbn');
            foreach($booklist as $onebook) {
                \DB::insert('insert into wantedbooks (isbn,user_id) values(?,2)', array($onebook));
            }
        return response("submitted for user ID: " . $uid);
    }
```

Once I confirmed that that information was captured I tried the following-

Controller(results in Array to String Conversion error):

```
    public function wanted(Request $request)
    {
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;
        $booklist = Input::get('isbn');
            foreach($booklist as $onebook) {
                \DB::insert('insert into wantedbooks (isbn,user_id) values(?,?)', [array($onebook),$uid)];
            }
        return response("submitted for user ID: " . $uid);
    }
```

Form from the view:

```
<form action='wanted' method='POST'>
     <div class='form-group'>
             <input type="text" name="isbn[]" placeholder="enter isbn...">
             <input type="text" name="isbn[]" placeholder="enter isbn...">
             <input type="text" name="isbn[]" placeholder="enter isbn...">
             <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
         <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add books</button>
```

I'm honestly losing track of the things I've tried, but these are the ones that I think I remember accurately enough. Any suggestions or information about what I'm doing wrong? I'm a total beginner, as I'm sure is quite evident by now.

EDIT:
Working code, but allowing a blank field still produces an error

```
public function wanted(Request $request)
    {
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;
        $booklist = Input::get('isbn');
            foreach($booklist as $onebook) {
                if($onebook === '') continue;
                DB::table('wantedbooks')->insert(['isbn' => $onebook, 'user_id' => $uid]);
            }
        return response("submitted for user ID: " . $uid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `array($onebook)` with `$onebook` and don't write raw SQL:

```
DB::table('wantedbooks')->insert(['isbn' => $onebook, 'user_id' => $uid]);
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that out as soon as I get back to my computer, Thanks, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: That seems to work. However, if one field is left blank I get an error. Is there a way to make fields optional? For example, if the user only wants to add 2 books, they can leave the third field blank and that field will just be ignored.

Comment: Yes, it's using the query builder.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to ninja edit my post, but I wasn't fast enough. I'll make sure to look at the query builder docs. Do you have any suggestion as far as allowing a user to leave a field blank without causing an error?

Comment: Add this before `DB::table(...`: `if($onebook === '') continue;`

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hmmm, I still get the same error. Maybe I have it it the wrong spot. I added the code to the end of the original question. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `if(is_null($onebook)) continue;`

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a slightly different approach, in essence not much different than what you started with.

1. create a model for your table. You can do it manually, you can do it via CLI.

`php artisan make:model WantedBook`

2. Edit the model, add the table, fields that are fillable etc. I'll provide an example, adjust accordingly, don't copy paste (since you won't learn that way and I made it wrong deliberately).

File: `WantedBook.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

class WantedBook extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'wantedbooks';
    // The rest is up to you, there's only 1 or 2 lines of code missing here
}
```

3. Write less code in your controller. Less code = faster to read, faster to understand, unless you are a hipster programmer who deliberately makes everything unreadable, don't be that guy.

Controller action (can be shorter, but this one is just fine for readability):

```
public function wanted(Request $request)
{
    $booklist= $request->input('isbn', []);

    foreach($isbn as $isbn)
    {
        $record = App\WantedBook::create(['isbn' => $isbn, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
    }

    return response("submitted for user ID: " . Auth::user()->id);
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't post code that works out of the box, the reason is so no one copy pastes it. If you think that approach using a model-concept looks ok to you, then try to take away from this example as much as you can.

If you're simply after a fix for your code, then a kind soul will appear who will provide it.

Good luck with Laravel and PHP!

Comment: I have a model for it, and explored that route a bit. However, I think I'll try it out again with that info as a guide.